# Rake: Deploy to Heroku if tests pass

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, rake, minitest

How can I write a rake script that will deploy to Heroku only if my test suite passes?

I am using Minitest tests, and right now the relevant part of my Rakefile looks like this:

```
task :test do
  $LOAD_PATH.unshift('tests')
  Dir.glob('./tests/spec_*.rb').each { |file| require file}
  Dir.glob('./tests/test_*.rb').each { |file| require file}
end

task :deploy do
  sh "git push heroku master"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the minitests' tests fail the rake returns exit code 1, so if you call the tests from a capistrano task and check for the exit code you can just exit the script.

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Runs test before deploying, can't deploy unless they pass"
  task :tests do
    puts "--> Running tests, please wait ..."
    unless system "RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake"
      puts "Tests failed"
      exit 1
    else
      puts "Tests passed"
    end
  end
end
```